# error when he tried update ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to update my version of ubuntu server

I execute the command `sudo apt-get update` and everything seems to be going well but when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` this error appears somebody could help me?

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

1 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y

perl: warning: Setting locale failed.

perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.

perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.

Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable

Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Did you try https://askubuntu.com/?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, `ldconfig` perhaps have been moved from `libc6` to `libc-bin`. Use the following commands to download and extract the `libc-bin` package:

```
apt-get download libc-bin
dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb unpackdir/
```

Next you need to copy these files:

```
sudo cp unpackdir/sbin/ldconfig /sbin/
```

Now you need to make sure that things are in order. Run these commands to ensure that:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer get from [Fix: Can’t exec “locale”: No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm](https://itsfoss.com/fix-exec-locale-file-directory/)